# "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function" triggered by different apps

Tags: php, lamp

In the last 3 days I've been struggling to get a couple of PHP apps(phpmyadmin and drupal 7) working on my Kubuntu 15.04 box and consistently receive a "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function" error I cannot figure out why.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled those apps and also the whole lamp stack, making sure there are no unmet dependencies(at least I think so...), to no avail and still get the white screen on the browser and from /var/log/apache2/error.log can read the same errors as listed below:

- When launching http://localhost/drupal/install.php:

  ```
  [:error] [pid 20641] [client 127.0.0.1:45554] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function json_encode() in /var/www/drupal/includes/common.inc on line 5095
  ```

  --> the content of the referred file on line 5095 being:

  ```
  // Encode <, >, ', &, and " using the json_encode() options parameter.
  return json_encode($var, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_QUOT);
  ```
- When launching localhost/phpmyadmin:

  ```
  [:error] [pid 20645] [client 127.0.0.1:45623] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function __() in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/core.lib.php on line 235
  ```

  --> the content of the referred file on line 235 to 237 being:

  ```
  // these variables are used in the included file libraries/error.inc.php
  $error_header = __('Error');
  $lang = $GLOBALS['available_languages'][$GLOBALS['lang']][1];
  $dir = $GLOBALS['text_dir'];
  ```

Although the listed errors affect different files, that I don't understand what are for, it appears to me that they must be related and part of the same problem. I have also experienced the same situation trying to run Adminer but don't have the error log anymore... Furthermore, when calling `phpinfo()` the report is served and it looks like php is running all right. Have to say also that I don't know much about Linux.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is not really Ubuntu-related, but you are missing some extensions for PHP.

To add this particular extension to your system, issue this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-json
```

Or even better, to have all the supported extensions installed:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-*
```